# Erro no repositório git:

Tags: git, github

Parece que fiz alguma burrada com o repositório do Git subjacente e foi quebrado, deixando inválido.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Erro:

> error: pathspec 'development' did not match any file(s) known to git.

Usei esses comandos, mas não teve efeito.

```
rm .git/refs/remotes/origin/development

git fetch

git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/development
```

Comment: Você consegue checar se a _branch_ existe remotamente?

Comment: @StatelessDev  Sim, mas... Encontrei uma solução mais eficaz e rápida. Fiz o Git clone novamente, apenas copiei a pasta  "node_modules" e colei. Deu certo.

Comment: @Letimberg, como resolveu o problema, sugiro criar uma resposta para sua própria pergunta, explicando como resolveu :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem diferentes razões para este erro ocorrer.

No seu caso, parece que você removeu acidentalmente a branch de `development` do repositório com `git branch -D development`. Neste caso, para resolver seria preciso recrir a branch local novamente com:

```
git checkout -b development
```

Ou, se for uma alternativa, faça o `git clone` novamente do repositório :).